# Buggy interaction of itemize environment, tabularx package and exam document class

Tags: tabularx, itemize, exam

When combining tabularx with the exam class, I have a problem that the question numbering and number of marks for questions is sometimes suppressed when using itemize.  I've created a minimal illustration of the problem below.  For a comparison between buggy behaviour, and behaviour working as expected, uncomment the commented line which resolves the issue: it only seems to manifest when the question starts directly with a tabularx environment containing an itemize environment:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}  
\question[3]
% B % Including this makes things work
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X}
\begin{itemize}
\item B
\end{itemize}
\end{tabularx}
\end{questions}                     
\end{document}
```

I have a hacky way around this for now.  My question is: **where should this be reported**?  Should this be considered a bug in the exam document class or in the tabularx environment (and where does one report bugs for these)?

Comment: you could use `\leavevmode` rather than `B`

Comment: for exam class there is an email addresss in the file, for tabularx the latex2e github issue tracker (but ideally without using an external class) but I'll look later